# Actualice a Andriod Studio 2.3.2 y se cierra automáticamente el emulador

Tags: android-studio

Actualice el Android Studio, y cuando presiono el botón de `play` empieza a compilar, se abre una ventana de emulador pero se cierra al instante, no puedo ejecutar ningún código porque el emulador no funciona, y Android Studio solo muestra este mensaje:

> Waiting for target device to come online

¿Quien sabe como solucionar esto?

Aun no puedo solucionarlo, intenté lanzarlo por el Terminal y me dice creo que lo cierra por lo siguiente:

**Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 0M**

Comment: Revisa el Log de Android Studio , ve a Help > Show Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busque [como ejecutar el emulador en línea de comandos,](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) lo primero es ir a: `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools.`

Desde ese lugar ejecutar: `./emulator -list-avds` esto nos dará una lista de emuladores que tenemos, a mi me muestra el único que tengo configurado: `Nexus_6_API_25`.

Luego ejecute esta línea: `./emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_25 -netdelay none -netspeed full`

Pero sucedió lo mismo, y me mostró esto en pantalla:

> emulator: WARNING: encryption is off Warning: requested RAM 1536M too
>   high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 0M Hax is
>   enabled Hax ram_size 0x0 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt
>   mode.

Finalmente buscando encontre esto que me pide que reinstale este software [Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) y funciono :D